# C# Compute Time Using Query

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am developing an Attendance Monitoring System and I need to compute the time difference between OutTime and InTime. The problem is I can't do it because the InTime value is in the Database, I can't seem to parameterize it. My query works with Access' query mode but not with  C#. Here's my code for the time out button.

```
 private void savetimeout()
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = @"    UPDATE TimeinTimeout 
                                    SET OutTime = @1 AND HoursWorked = ROUND(([OutTime]-[InTime])*24,2)
                                    WHERE EmployeeID = @2 AND InDate = @3";
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());


        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved!");
        this.Hide();
        Form1 Mm = new Form1();
        Mm.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: Are OutTime, InTime and InDate fields of type DateTIme? Please show the actual database table schema and tell us what values are present in the table at the moment you run this query.

Comment: Yes all are date/time, so what's next?

Comment: OutTime should be set to the DateTime.Now, while, HoursWorked could be set with the difference between OutTime - InTime

Comment: Indeed, My OutTime is set as Datetime.Now.ToShortDateString, But how do I retrieve the value of InTime from the database and compute it in update query if I press the time out button

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a field `OutTime` that you want to set with the current time and, in the same query, you want to calc the difference between the known value inside the field `InTime` and the current time.

You could use a query like this

```
command.CommandText = @"UPDATE TimeinTimeout 
                        SET HoursWorked = @1-[InTime],
                        OutTime = @2
                        WHERE EmployeeID = @3 AND InDate = @4";

command.Parameters.Add("@1", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
command.Parameters.Add("@2", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
// Is this field really a string? 
// If not use the appropriate type and convert the textbox.text
command.Parameters.Add("@3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@4", OleDbType.Date) = DateTime.Today;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice that to not confuse the database engine you should specify exactly what your parameters are. Using AddWithValue with DateTime field and passing a string creates a problem because your database engine needs to convert these strings back to datetime values and this conversion could produce unexpected problems. Always specify exactly the type of your parameters.

Comment: It says "Index was outside the bounds of the array" same as my previous attempts

Comment: No idea, it's just a messagebox

Comment: Sorry. but I can't teach you how to debug your program. The error message seems not to be related to this code. I can only say. Press F9 to the first line of this code. Then run your program. If the breakpoint is hit the Visual Studio debugger will stop at the line. Then you can proceed step by step pressing F10 until you reach the line that causes the error. If the breakpoint is not hit then the error is before this code.

Comment: I did some searching, Don't you think it should be AddWithValue? What does VarWChar mean? Is it that different with VarChar 'cause EmployeeID's Data Type is Text in MS Access

Comment: A VarWChar is _A variable-length, null-terminated stream of Unicode characters_ while a VarChar is _A variable-length stream of non-Unicode characters_ Because all string values in NET are Unicode then you specify your value to be a Unicode string. And no, do not use AddWithValue, expecially with dates [Can we stop to use addwithvalue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: The code works but the value of hours is high like 1027368 the difference should be 0.something, the data type is text of HoursWorked in the DB

Comment: To subtraction from two date is a numeric value that represents a date. If you write this value in a string field you will see the numeric representation not the DateTime value. You should write the value to another DateTime field

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just passed my defense yester day :)